# Possible distinction for folklore

Tags: discussion

I was editing the animals tag today, and I needed an explanation for why [wendigo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wendigo) is on topic, but [chupacabra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chupacabra#History) is not.

*(I love chupacabras and even wrote a book about them, but the legend only seems to be a of couple decades old, thus while it is folklore, it may not be said to be traditional until everyone who was alive when the first National Enquirer story is no longer living.)*

Essentially, a practice or belief does not become traditional until the originators have passed into memory, which is to day it has passed from [living memory](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/in_%28or_within%29_living_memory).

Comment: When did we decide chupacabras are off topic?

Comment: @yannis  I thought we were avoiding contemporary folklore (commonly held to be under the umbrella of "conspiracy theories".)  I know we did get one question on that lake monster in Australia, but I thought that was tied into traditional indigenous beliefs.  I'd be psyched if contemporary folklore was on-topic, as it is a subject of some interest!

Comment: Contemporary folklore is one of these topics that we wasted a lot of time discussing in Meta in the early days of the site, without ever (as long as I remember) reaching a definitive conclusion. Worse, we never bothered actually testing the topic on the main site. I think it's about time we give it a chance. If we can host [scientology questions](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scientology), I don't see why we can't host questions about chupacabras.